# Bootstrap 4 using Flexbox with responsive columns but column unresponsive content

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-4

I need to create the following layout:

Initial:
[image]

After resizing:

[image]

[image]

So, Group 1 and Group 2 don't wrap.

But what I get is this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-md-row flex-column">
  <div class="mr-auto p-2">
    <input type="button" value="Group 1"/>
    <input type="button" value="Group 1"/>
  </div>
  <div class="p-2">
    <input type="button" value="Group 2"/>
    <input type="button" value="Group 2"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/HGOz68PZXl)

Thanks for the help.

Update.
If I add flex-column to the top div I kinda get what I need but then when I resize Group 2 goes into the new row way too early. There is still plenty of space between Groups there is no need for two rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `flex-wrap` to

```
<div class="d-flex flex-md-row">
```

so it becomes

```
<div class="d-flex flex-md-row flex-wrap">
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1hfn04k9/)